# Disable postback on jQuery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu, postback

Is there a way to block jquery modal dialog from popping up each time dropdownlist postback is called? Because seems like the whole page refreshes hence my jquery modal dialog also will pop-up but I want to block that from happening, I only need it to be popup when the page is loaded first time.

Here's my Javascript, tried using the event.preventDefault but it's not working still.

```
$(function() {
    $("#ddlNo").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        modal: true,
        show: { effect: "fade", duration: 1000 },
        buttons: {
            "Confirm": function() {
                var bValid = true;
                allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");
                bValid = bValid && check(true);

                if (bValid) {
                    $("#users tbody").append("<tr>" +
                "<td>" + agree.val() + "</td>" + "</tr>");
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        },
        close: function() {
            allFields.val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
        }
    });
});
```

Here's my markup:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNo" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsEq"
    DataTextField="No" DataValueField="Id" AutoPostBack="true">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just thought I should share a solution to this. Found a workable solution, for those who needs it, you can use:

```
<%if (!this.IsPostBack)
      { %>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            //logic
        });
    </script>
    <%} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a function that open an popup, the from the page load event at server-side, let's register a client script when `Postback != True`, this script will call your js script to open the dialog box. Hope this help.

In case you don't know how to use register client script you can look at it at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need it to postback when someone changes the dropdownlist, then change it to AutoPostBack="false"

If you do need it to postback, put it inside an UpdatePanel with the other controls dependent on its state with the proper async syntax like the example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.asyncpostbacktrigger.aspx

Comment: Hi Rob G, can this be done on client-side scripting? Instead of using the UpdatePanel?